# I can't seem to get css or programmatically changing imagebuttons image

Tags: asp.net, css

this is a two part problem, one is with CSS and the other with codebehind..
Here is my navigation code for my buttons...

```
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Buttons/upviewassets.png"     OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Buttons/upaddassets.png"     OnClick="ImageButton2_Click" />
```

All the buttons are side by side. On the OnClick() event my code is this...

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "Buttons/dnviewassets.png";
        ImageButton2.ImageUrl = "Buttons/upaddassets.png";
        //Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");
    }

    protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "Buttons/upviewassets.png";
        ImageButton2.ImageUrl = "Buttons/dnaddassets.png";
        //Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");        
    }
```

When i comment out the response.redirect it works, but i need to be able to use the response.redirect because this is in a masterpage and i need these buttons to redirect to other pages, when I run it with the response.redirect method the images don't change. As well, when i first run it without the response.redirect, when i click on the button it jumps quickly and goes back to where it should be, but then works fine everytime after.

So for the second part, I have also tried using css to change the imagebuttons image but couldn't get it to work, and i have searched online and went through tutorials but even when using the code provided it didn't work properly and my buttons kept jumping.
I'm trying to mimic a look of tabs in the master page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would save a flag in the session in click event and retrieve it in redirected page PreRender:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PaintButtons();
    }
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

And my PaintButtons method:

```
private void PaintButtons()
{
    if(Session["ImageButton_Toggled"] == null )
    {               
        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "Buttons/upviewassets.png";
        ImageButton2.ImageUrl = "Buttons/upaddassets.png";
    }
    else
    {
        int toggleId = 1;
        int.TryParse(Session["ImageButton_Toggled"].ToString(), out toggleId);

        if (toggleId == 1)
        {
            ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "Buttons/dnviewassets.png";
            ImageButton2.ImageUrl = "Buttons/upaddassets.png";
        }
        else
        {
            ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "Buttons/upviewassets.png";
            ImageButton2.ImageUrl = "Buttons/dnaddassets.png";
        }
    }
}
```

Click event methods in my masterpage:

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Session["ImageButton_Toggled"] = 1;
    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");
}

protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Session["ImageButton_Toggled"] = 2;
    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");        
}
```

Now I can redirect to any page I want, and my masterpage will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try this as well. It seems like a lot of work for something that would seem so simple

Comment: I tried your answer, the other answer was essentially the same. But when it firsts loads and click on either of the buttons they seem to jump out and comeback in, what would be the cause of that?, I need a fluid transition like when using ajax tab container

Comment: I moved the code to prerender from page load to stop flicker.

Comment: It may be my browser because i'm not getting the same effect as you are. It still look like a pageload of the buttons again, it only does it on the first click of both buttons then it even itself out and doesn't do the pageload look

Comment: Here is an answer:[http://stackoverflow.com/a/1568252/690329](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1568252/690329).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it explained what the issue was. It was the conclusion I was coming to because even though there is a masterpage there is also a refresh everytime. maybe what I should do is use the ajax tabcontainer and that would stop with the refresh of the entire page